# How does History SE differ from the rest of the internet for historical facts?

Tags: discussion

I was [asked](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46083/what-are-ways-mothers-day-is-officially-celebrated-in-your-country) why not ask Wiki for information? IMO I find the answers places like Wiki misses and a feeling of humanity here.

What technical reasons why History SE is better? 
Should History SE be used as the first stop a question on History?

Comment: I wish we could say our  answers were better referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

History.SE is meant for questions that are not easily answered with a simple google search. We are not here to supply basic facts, but rather to explain the whys and the hows, to give facts context, and to locate obscure answers not usually addressed by mainstream sources.

> Should History SE be used as the first stop a question on History?

No. That would probably be Wikipedia.